# How to set up Power Automate with every combination of 5 conditions

Tags: power-automate

I have a survey with 5 different yes/no questions. If they answer yes to any question, more questions will appear. I want to create a flow that sends an email to the survey responder with all of the questions **and** answers they responded to (but none of the questions they didn't respond to if they didn't select "yes").

The 5 questions are not dependent on each other so there can be any combination of the 5 yes/no questions. I started creating Conditions in my flow but soon realized that there are a possible 120 combinations of these 5 yes/no responses! I'm wondering if there is an easier, softer way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you can provide an example of the JSON, I reckon we can help.